# How to use alpha matting parameter in remove() function?

Tags: python, image-processing, background

I am trying to remove background of an image using python library 'rembg'.

I tried an alpha matting example given in 'Advanced usage' section [here](https://pypi.org/project/rembg/). It works properly. However, I want to apply alpha matting inside python code. Additionally, an example given in 'Usage as a library' (Input and output as bytes) also works properly.

Is there any way to apply alpha matting inside code. Any help, example code on that would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = remove(
    f,
    alpha_matting=True,
    alpha_matting_foreground_threshold=240,
    alpha_matting_background_threshold=10,
    alpha_matting_erode_structure_size=10,
    alpha_matting_base_size=1000,
)
```